# How to deep watch an object in angularjs excluding a specified pattern?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

There is an nested object with certain properties which i don't want to be watched. It could be a pattern of properties starting with perhaps "_".

Here's a sample structure.

```
$scope.ObjectToBeWatched = {

  "company": {
    "ts": {
      "_msg": {"nm":""},
      "status": "success"
    },
    "ids": [
      "000000010",
      "000000011"
    ]
  },
  "_f": [
    {
      "code": "TY_IO",
      "status": "fail"
    }
  ]
}
```

Standard deep watch:

```
$scope.$watch("ObjectToBeWatched",function(newObj,oldObj){

},true);
```

Right now the watch is firing for any any change in any properties which is expected. So in above case any changes to properties

```
_msg, _f
```

should not fire.

Thanks for help.

Comment: you can pass to watch function that can return needed object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
$scope.$watch(function($scope) {
  return $scope.listOfBigObjects.
      map(function(bigObject) {
        return bigObject.foo.
            fieldICareAbout;
      });
}, myHandler, true);
```

This grabs only the props you care about from the objects in an array.  You can use an expression to check for certain field types inside the object map.  If you don't have an array just skip that part.

Underscore has tons of functional methods to help w/ this as well if 'map' isn't exactly what you need to return fields you care about.

Comment: Thanks. Could this be used if I have nested properties? I was hoping for an exclusion rather than inclusion.

Comment: Inclusion/exclusion is just how you check the key.  You can grab keys easily with underscores 'keys' method.  You can also use underscores 'omit' function to omit blacklisted keys, like anything that starts with an underscore.  As for nested, you will have to traverse the object tree.